# Converting Julia nested list to multidimensional array

Tags: julia

Given a Julia list of lists:

```
data = [[1,2],[4,5]]
```

which has type `Vector{Int64}`, how can I convert this to a 2D data type (e.g. `2×2 Matrix{Int64}`) so that I can index it like `data[:,2]`? I tried `hcat` or `vcat` but couldn't get the result that I wanted. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hcat` works fine:

```
julia> hcat([[1,2],[4,5]]...)
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4
 2  5
```

The thing is that vectors are *column*-vectors in Julia (unlike in NumPy, for example), so you should `h`orisontally con`cat`enate them to get the matrix.

If you use `vcat`, you'll stack them on top of each other, getting one tall vector:

```
julia> vcat([[1,2],[4,5]]...)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 4
 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to NumPy indeed, so that extra bit of context helps. What does the `...` operator do in this case?

Comment: @RvdV, it's the "splat" operator - basically the same as the `*` operator in `function(*[1,2,3,4,5])` in Python

Comment: Clear, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
julia> reduce(hcat, data)
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4
 2  5
```

Comment: This also works great for splitting strings in matrices: `reduce(hcat, split.(readdlm("file.csv"), ""))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Iterators` for that. Once you have a Vector simply use `reshape`.

```
reshape( collect(Iterators.flatten([[1,2],[4,5]])), 2,2 )

2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4
 2  5
```